# htaccess file redirecting malformed URLs

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, http-status-code-404

I have what appears to be a correctly-configured *.htaccess* file, which redirects *http* to *https* and individually 301s defined URLs.

```
DirectoryIndex app.php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

# RedirectS //

Redirect 301 /content/166/b6seriespremiumbodyday/nightcamerairlightingwith49mmzoomlenssonyproelectronicspack.aspx   https://www.example.co.uk/shop/cctv-cameras/day-night/b6-4-9mm-lens/

# .. loads more redirects here (left out for brevity)

Redirect 301 /content/93/bnc/    https://www.example.co.uk/shop/cctv-accessories/cctv-cable-accessories/bnc-to-scart-adapter-for-television-monitors

# // RedirectS



# DOMAIN

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.co\.uk
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^dev\.example\.co\.uk
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example\.local
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.local
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]

# // DOMAIN



# HTTPS

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^dev\.example\.co\.uk
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example\.local
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.local
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# // HTTPS

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]

RewriteCond %{ENV:Redirect_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^app\.php(/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$2 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule .? - [L]

# Rewrite all other queries to the front controller.
RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}/app.php [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_alias.c>
    RedirectMatch 302 ^/$ /app.php/
    # RedirectTemp cannot be used instead
</IfModule>
</IfModule>

## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 month"
ExpiresDefault "access 1 week"
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
```

The problem comes when someone either enters a wrong address OR a link breaks on site; for instance, *[example.com/khdkhdkjh](http://www.example.com/khdkhdkjh)* ends up on the custom 404 page **BUT** is shown there as *https://www.example.com/khdkhdkjh/*.

No big deal you might think; however, Google Webmaster tools is showing this as a "faulty 404" because of the rewrite which takes in *advance* of
the 404.

How do I structure htaccess to ensure that malformed URLs are actioned **BEFORE** the 301 redirect?

Comment: Show your full .htaccess in question